# stuck on for loop with variable depth

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame called df2 that has 1501 data points

```
 Depth <- seq(0, 1500, by = 1)
 Temp <- rev(seq(1, 10, by = 0.006))

 D0 <- 0 
 Dend <- 1000
 r <- 2 

 days <- 100 


 D <- rep(NA, days+1)
 D <- D0
 Temp <- T0

 for (time in seq_len(steps)){  
  if (tail(D,1) >= Dend)  break
   D[time + 1] <- r + D[time] 
   Temp[time] <-  Temp[time]
   }
```

I can't seem to couple Temp with D. Using this line of code (Temp[time] <-  Temp[time]), I get Temp every m for 1500.

Comment: You for-loop is equivalent with `D <- D0 + r*(0:n_steps)`

Comment: should be fixed -

Answer (score 1):

One approach to simplify things a bit with `seq` using `by=` and `length.out=`.

Then we can use `merge` to join the results back to `df2`. It needs to be a `data.frame` with names to merge onto, so I changed your `cbind` to `data.frame`.

```
Depth <- seq(0, 1500, by = 1)
Temp <- rev(seq(1, 10, by = 0.006))
df2 <- data.frame(Depth, Temp)
D0 <- 0
days <- 107
r <- 40

Result <- data.frame(Day = 0:days,
                     Depth =seq(from = D0, by= r ,length.out = days + 1))
Result <- merge(Result,df2,all.x=TRUE)
Result
#    Depth Day  Temp
#1       0   0 10.00
#2      40   1  9.76
#3      80   2  9.52
#4     120   3  9.28
#5     160   4  9.04
#...
```

By using `all.x=TRUE` we will get `NA` when there is no value in `df2` for that Depth.

Comment: Please edit your question with some form of data on how `r` varies with `Temp`.

Comment: This website is focused on programing questions. We can help you come up with an approach to program your experimental design. However, the purpose is not to design your experiment for you, particularly when we don't have access to even a sample of the data you want to use. If you update your question with *data* and a better description of your desired output, we are more likely to be able to help.